# Changing Char of a textbox to it's next char

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt, I want to make something which will show the next char of the char input.

For example, I entered 'a' into a QTextEdit, it automatically turns to 'b' in another QTextEdit, and when I again enter 'b', it turns to 'c'. Which algorithm is perfect for this?

Comment: QTextEdit* I'm sorry, my mistake.

Comment: What does "turns to" mean? I'm imagining that you want the 'a' deleted from the first edit box, but that's just a guess. Can you clarify? If I'm wrong, what are you trying to achieve when several characters are entered?

Comment: Alright, so for example, in TextBox1, i entered 'a'. What I want is that in TextBox2, there will be a char added which is 'b'. So if i write "Hello" in TextBox1, it will appear "Ifmmp" in TextBox2. Hope you understood.

Comment: Do you know how to read a string from a QT text box? Write a string to a text box? Detect when a user changes text in a text box? If you don't, those would be good questions to ask. And if you do know, then I'm not sure that your question directly involves QT. This may be too many questions at once.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, you want to do the following things (which are not code):

1. Detect a change in the first input box
2. Decide how to modify the second text box given the value of the first text box
3. Update the second text box

Step 2 might be (from your example) to ensure the text has more than one character and, assuming its a std::string, get `text[text.length() -1]` and Step 3 might be to get the text of the second text box, append that character and assign it.

This would work for a modifiable or non-modifiable second text box since it does not re-modify each character in the string -- just the added one.

But, you need to clearly define what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the characters directly, you can set each character like `tChar = iChar + 1`.  It'd get a little wonky if you put in something that isn't a letter (spaces or enter key).  In that case you'd wrap it with `if (iChar >= 'a' && iChar <= 'Z') {` which uses the 'n' syntax to alias the actual number codes.  Another method would be to subclass the Qtextedit control and overload the `void Qtextedit::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent* event)` virtual function to intercept the key strokes and check that way. The comparison is similar, but you'd use Qt::Key_A instead of 'a' to check that it's a letter key, then modify the resulting char appropriately.

See also: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtextedit.html